# primefaces busy indicator on page redirects to avoid dual submission

Tags: primefaces

I am using primefaces 3.4, I want to show the busy indicator on the page when   the page is redirecting to a new page ?
I have a page with command button   the action listener returns string to next resource and the next resource takes time to render the page I was able to show busy indicator for ajaxrequest using

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="$.blockUI();" onerror="alert('error')" onsuccess="$.unblockUI();"/>
```

but for page redirects can I show the same busy indicator ?
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not doing your request via Ajax.
This code works for me:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
<h:outputScript library="js" name="jquery.blockUI.js" />
    <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="navigate" action="test.xhtml?faces-redirect=true"/>
    </h:form> 
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="$.blockUI();" onerror="$.unblockUI();alert('error');" />
</h:body>
</html>
```